# How to write following code in list comprehension form?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Trying to convert following code in list comprehension form but I am getting syntax error for "+=" near else

```
def lucky_sum(a, b, c):
    ip = [a, b, c]
    sum = 0
    for i in ip:
        if i ==13:
            return sum
        else:
            sum+=i
    return sum
```

I tried this:

```
def lucky_sum(a, b, c):
    ip = [a, b, c]
    sum = 0
    res = [sum if i == 13 else sum += i for i in ip]
    return sum
```

Comment: You don't *have* to use list comprehensions.

Comment: I think they just want to. @Keith

Comment: Tip: Don't use keywords for variable names.

Comment: List comprehension are chiefly for creating lists. You aren't doing that

Comment: Got it. Thank you

Comment: @Axium Technically, `sum` is not a keyword. But yes, it is a built-in function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's impossible to use list comprehension here, since you're assigning something (this case is `+=`, but still has `=` in it), so you have to stay with a loop, list comprehensions aren't the stuff that could be used for anything.

So stay with the loop.

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension isn't adapted here, but that doesn't mean that we cannot use functionnal programming.

Use built-in `sum` and `itertools.takewhile` to end iteration when meeting 13. Creates a one-liner.

```
import itertools


def lucky_sum(a, b, c):
    return sum(itertools.takewhile(lambda x:x!=13,[a, b, c]))

print(lucky_sum(1,2,3))
print(lucky_sum(1,13,3))
```

prints `6` then `1`

A variable number of arguments version:

```
def lucky_sum(*ip):
    return sum(itertools.takewhile(lambda x:x!=13,ip))
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Don't do a list comprehension here. They exist, so you can create lists more easily.

Just to see if it is possible (with no external module) I tried and came up with this:

```
def lucky_sum2(*args):
    return sum(el if el != 13 else next(iter([])) for el in args)
```

It abuses the fact, that `next(iter([]))` raises a `StopIteration` (which will soon be deprecated, though).

Don't use this, please